# Multimedia web applications that perform well

Tags: html, javascript, video

There are a few multimedia web applications like [PHPMotion](http://demo.phpmotiontemplates.com/default/), [ClipBucket](http://clipbucket.net/v2/) that allow playback of multimedia files.

Beside the mentioned multimedia web applications, are there other similar multimedia web applications that are resource-efficient, awesome playback speed (no play-stop-play-stop) and have many features like those in [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/)?

It should support at least 3 different type of media format (e.g. mp4, flv)

**UPDATE**

As it seems that multimedia web applications are quite rare. I am also open for Multimedia Javascript Player. (Multimedia Player "made of" Javascript)

Comment: The first two are full-on hosted services, and jPlayer isn't quite what I'd call an "application" but just a player that you'd have to *integrate* into an app/web site. Can you explain a bit more what you're actually after here? Do you just want a decent player(in which case what's wrong with jPlayer?) or something to actually *manage* your media besides also playing it etc.?

Comment: @Su' There is nothing wrong with JPlayer. What I am actually after is a web application or a flash player can really have a playlist like - http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/javascript/playlist/youtube.html but I want it to have the features of JPlayer and allow dynamic changing of code for the playlist and it should preferable to behave like the mentioned multimedia web application.

Comment: @Su', do you have any good recommendation for javascript type video player that I can just use on a web site? If you do, just insert as a answer and I will mark it as correct. (cause I intend to change my direction from multimedia web application to multimedia javascript player)

Answer (score 0):

JW Player is one of the market leaders and is free for non-commercial use. JW Player Supports HTML and HTML5 as well as the following formats:

**Video Formats** - MP4 - M4V - F4V - WebM - FLV

**Audio Formats** - AAC - M4A - F4A - MP3 - Vorbis - OGG - OGA

You can read more about [JW Player features here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/features/).